# What's the relationship of a Router with its loopback interface in logic?

Tags: router, ip, ip-address, interface, loopback

I have a Router1 with a loopback 0 connected to the Router2:

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

the interface brief is bellow:

```
Router1>show ip interface brief 
Interface              IP-Address      OK? Method Status                Protocol 
GigabitEthernet0/0/0   10.0.12.1       YES manual up                    up 
GigabitEthernet0/0/1   unassigned      YES unset  administratively down down 
Loopback0              1.1.1.1         YES manual up                    up 
Vlan1                  unassigned      YES unset  administratively down down
```

the ip route is bellow:

```
Router1#show ip route 
Codes: L - local, C - connected, S - static, R - RIP, M - mobile, B - BGP
       D - EIGRP, EX - EIGRP external, O - OSPF, IA - OSPF inter area
       N1 - OSPF NSSA external type 1, N2 - OSPF NSSA external type 2
       E1 - OSPF external type 1, E2 - OSPF external type 2, E - EGP
       i - IS-IS, L1 - IS-IS level-1, L2 - IS-IS level-2, ia - IS-IS inter area
       * - candidate default, U - per-user static route, o - ODR
       P - periodic downloaded static route

Gateway of last resort is not set

     1.0.0.0/32 is subnetted, 1 subnets
C       1.1.1.1/32 is directly connected, Loopback0
     10.0.0.0/8 is variably subnetted, 2 subnets, 2 masks
C       10.0.12.0/24 is directly connected, GigabitEthernet0/0/0
L       10.0.12.1/32 is directly connected, GigabitEthernet0/0/0
```

I have a question, what's the logic relationship of Router1 and its loopback0?

if we regard the loopback0 as its a logic router interface, the `route` `1.1.1.1/32` should be `L`, because the Gig0/0/0's ip is `L`.

if we regard the loopback0 as a independent Server(because its relationship is `connected`), it should have something to connect the loopback0, right?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Loopback interfaces are *virtual* interfaces that are considered directly connected interfaces. Your `Loopback0` interface is defined with a `/32` network, which, by definition, is a local route. How you are seeing it when you show the routes is how the `/32` is reported. If you had addressed it with a longer mask, you would also get a `L`ocal route (the `/32` address).

Your `GigabitEthernet0/0/0` interface is a physical interface directly connected to the `10.0.12.0/24` network, and its `L`ocal address on that network is `10.0.12.1`.

I tested this.

First, with a `/32` network on the loopback:

```
Router1(config)#int lo12345
Router1(config-if)#ip address 10.11.12.13 255.255.255.255
Router1(config-if)#do sh ip int br                       
Interface                  IP-Address      OK? Method Status                Protocol
  ...
Loopback12345              10.11.12.13     YES manual up                    up      
  ...
DFW-Router1(config-if)#do sh ip route                        
Codes: L - local, C - connected, S - static, R - RIP, M - mobile, B - BGP
       D - EIGRP, EX - EIGRP external, O - OSPF, IA - OSPF inter area 
       N1 - OSPF NSSA external type 1, N2 - OSPF NSSA external type 2
       E1 - OSPF external type 1, E2 - OSPF external type 2
       i - IS-IS, su - IS-IS summary, L1 - IS-IS level-1, L2 - IS-IS level-2
       ia - IS-IS inter area, * - candidate default, U - per-user static route
       o - ODR, P - periodic downloaded static route, H - NHRP, l - LISP
       a - application route
       + - replicated route, % - next hop override, p - overrides from PfR

Gateway of last resort is x.x.x.x to network 0.0.0.0

  ...
      10.0.0.0/32 is subnetted, 1 subnets
C        10.11.12.13 is directly connected, Loopback12345
  ...
```

Next, with a `/24` network on the loopback:

```
Router1(config-if)#ip address 10.11.12.13 255.255.255.0
Router1(config-if)#do sh ip int br
  ...
Loopback12345              10.11.12.13     YES manual up                    up      
  ...
Router1(config-if)#do sh ip route
Codes: L - local, C - connected, S - static, R - RIP, M - mobile, B - BGP
       D - EIGRP, EX - EIGRP external, O - OSPF, IA - OSPF inter area 
       N1 - OSPF NSSA external type 1, N2 - OSPF NSSA external type 2
       E1 - OSPF external type 1, E2 - OSPF external type 2
       i - IS-IS, su - IS-IS summary, L1 - IS-IS level-1, L2 - IS-IS level-2
       ia - IS-IS inter area, * - candidate default, U - per-user static route
       o - ODR, P - periodic downloaded static route, H - NHRP, l - LISP
       a - application route
       + - replicated route, % - next hop override, p - overrides from PfR

Gateway of last resort is x.x.x.x to network 0.0.0.0

  ...
      10.0.0.0/8 is variably subnetted, 2 subnets, 2 masks
C        10.11.12.0/24 is directly connected, Loopback12345
L        10.11.12.13/32 is directly connected, Loopback12345
  ...
```

It seems that if the interface address *is* the network address, you do not get a sparate `L`ocal address in the routing table for that network.