# Cisco ASA 5505- My subnet mask is different from Show Route

Tags: ipv4, cisco-asa, firewall, subnet, route

While I was troubleshooting a DNS issue on my 10.10.10.0/30 subnet, I noticed the Local (L) and Connected (C) has different values. I configured the 10.10.10.0 network to use 255.255.255.252 has the mask but I noticed a 255.255.255.255. Is this normal? if not how can I change it to the appropriate. please see the info below. Thanks in advance.

```
Gateway of last resort is 192.168.1.254 to network 0.0.0.0

S*    0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 [1/0] via 192.168.1.254, outside
C        10.10.10.0 255.255.255.252 is directly connected, Management
L        10.10.10.1 255.255.255.255 is directly connected, Management
C        192.168.1.0 255.255.255.0 is directly connected, outside
L        192.168.1.82 255.255.255.255 is directly connected, outside
C        192.168.2.0 255.255.255.0 is directly connected, inside
L        192.168.2.1 255.255.255.255 is directly connected, inside
```

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 4):

The `L` route is the local address assigned to the interface, and the `C` route is the network attached to the interface. That is completely normal (beyond a certain device code version) for interfaces that have smaller masks configured on them. If you configure an interface, e.g. a loopback, with a `/32` address, then you will not see a separate `L` entry for that interface, but if you configured an interface with a shorter mask, then you will see both.

There are several questions and answer here that explore this. For example, [this question and answer](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/q/54888/8499).